# Where does "ρ" come from in the primary objective function ?

Tags: svm, one-class

I'm trying to fully understand the **primary objective of one-class SVM function**.

This function is defined in paragraph 3.2 of [Enhancing One-class Support Vector Machines for
Unsupervised Anomaly Detection](http://met.guc.edu.eg/Repository/Faculty/Publications/479/One-class-SVM_anomaly-detection.pdf) as:

$$min_{\omega, \eta, \rho} ||\omega||^2 - \rho + \frac{1}{\nu n} \sum_{i=-1}^n \xi_i $$

subject to:
$$\omega^T \phi(x_i) \ge \rho - \xi_i$$
and to
$$\xi_i \ge 0$$

I understand perfectly why $||\omega||^2$ is here (thanks to this [wonderful link](https://youtu.be/_PwhiWxHK8o?t=1206)).

I also understand why $\frac{1}{\nu n} \sum_{i=-1}^n \xi_i $ is here, thanks to different links I read.

But I cannot figure out why $ - \rho\ $ is here. I seems this part is specific to one-class SVM. (Please find [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P126.pdf) the link to the original paper.)

So, where does this $ - \rho\ $ come from ?

Comment: The original article is here: http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~williams/papers/P132.pdf

 $\rho$ appears as the bias term (and they note it can be negative). I'm not actually sure that maximizing it is really necessary -there is a tradeoff involved between it and the error terms, but it's not immediately clear that this is necessary (needs a closer look). It may just be that including it makes it simpler to solve.